# Which is the best color space to detect motion of a very small object using opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to track a golf ball using the absdiff method and it does work quite well but am wondering if can I extend my tracking further even, what im doing at the moment is using the hsv color space extracting the v channel and getting the absdiff between the prev and curr mat

Comment: v band means lightness/brightness. so it is same as averaging RGB bands (grayscale) which means you don't use color information.

Comment: To not be considered as opinion based problem please put some example and further explanation then the best color-space reagarding your problem could be inferred

Comment: So if i merge the 3 channels after thresholding will I get better results, the ball is tiny at this point

Answer (score 0):

if the ball is white you can assume ball pixels have high grayscale values. Otherwise, you can filter a specific color in the hsv space:

http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html#gsc.tab=0